# site map generation problem

Tags: joomla, sef

I am using sef servicemap compaonent for my joomla site.it is not generating the sitemap properly.what the changer i need to do.

Thanks,
Raghu.P

Answer (score 0):

Download xmap http://joomla.vargas.co.cr/

It comes with lots of plugins to handle other components.